# Send SCPI Commands through Powershell using VISA

Tags: powershell, visa

I have to open a session the connection Address similar to GPIB::5::INSTR and Fire the SCPI command "*IDN?"
I need to do it through Powershell.

I found only one article : http://kckoay.blogspot.com/2008/07/use-powershell-to-send-scpi-command-to.html
and its not working

Any help Please!!

Answer (score 0):

I will be a similar thing soon, but no visa, only bit banging.  I did find this today on forums ni, "Default GPIB termination character" it is very important to get the instrument to respond.  Back in 1987, I did need to connect a logic analyzer to the IEEE-488 bus to isolate a failure where one master would send CR LF LF LF, it was working, the other master only sent CR the instrument would not respond.  The above discussion might help.